# How can I add and initialize objects in a vector without having the destructor for the existing objects called?

Tags: c++

I am working a homework assignment and have come across a problem when I added a destructor to my class.

From Assignment:

> The class will have a destructor that displays a message indicating that an object has "gone out of scope".

I've implemented this in my `rectangle` class by outputting to an `ofstream` object:

```
rectangle::~rectangle()
{
    RectOutput << "Object with length " << length << " and width " << width << " is now out of scope." << std::endl;
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that, I put these objects into a vector to make it easy to output to a table. Everything looked really good until I added the destructor. Due to the way vectors copy their data to a new internal array and delete the old array to increase the size, the destructor is called and the message is output several times in the creation of the objects.

Part of the constraints of this homework is that I had to initialize some of the objects with certain values. The choice to use a vector was my own. Here is the code of the initalization of the objects:

```
std::vector <rectangle> Rectangles;

//Initialize all of our rectangle objects within our vector
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle());
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle(7.1, 3.2));
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle(6.3));
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle(21.0, 21.0));
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle(Rectangles[1]));
```

And here is the output being produced by this:

> Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 7.1 and width 3.2 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 7.1 and width 3.2 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 6.3 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Value of 21 is invalid. Values must be greater than 0.0 and less than or equal to 20.0. Default of 1.0 used.
>   Value of 21 is invalid. Values must be greater than 0.0 and less than or equal to 20.0. Default of 1.0 used.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 7.1 and width 3.2 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 6.3 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 7.1 and width 3.2 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 6.3 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 1 and width 1 is now out of scope.
>   Object with length 7.1 and width 3.2 is now out of scope.

How can I initialize these objects in a vector without having the destructor being called repeatedly like this? I also tried to start off with `std::vector <rectangle> Rectangles(5);`, however this actually seems to call my default constructor 5 times, filling the vector with 5 default `rectangle` objects and then when I add to it the same effect is seen, except it is destructing the default objects.

Comment: If you want to be able to grow the container without reallocating, use `deque` or `list` instead of `vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Rectangles.emplace_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `Rectangles.push_back()` and you will still need [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) as mentioned by [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35835795/5475140)

Comment: Also he will need to remove the explicit creation of temporary object (i.e. `Rectangles.emplace_back(6.3);` etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you do e.g.

```
Rectangles.push_back(rectangle());
```

The expression `rectangle()` creates a *temporary object*. This object is then copied or moved into the vector, without destructing any "existing" object. What you see destructed is the temporary object.

Comment: The way I understand your explanation is that a temporary object is being created *outside* of the vector, and then a reference to that is passed to the vector, which the vector then copies? Then since it is only an expression it immediately goes out of scope and the destructor is called. Am I adding the objects to the vector in an unusual way?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade Your understanding is about right, and no you're not doing anything unusual.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reserve()` to allocate enough elements in the vector to hold all the rectangles you're going to insert into the vector.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This did indeed work, the destructor is now being called for the temporary objects that Joachim is talking about instead of each time the vector is resized.